# How to find out the cheapest shipping method and change the shipping label in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

So here's what I need to do: find out the cheapest shipping method and change the "Free Shipping" method label to "Free Shipping" + "Cheapest method label". This way the customer will be able to know what is the shipping method used for the free shipping.

First I thought about global variables.. then used the wp_options, but I am not certain if the wp_options are user shared or user-specific data.

Would you have any good ideas or corrections on the following code, which by the way isn't working? Thanks!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'wf_default_shipping_method', 10 );
function wf_default_shipping_method( $method ) {

    $the_cheapest_cost = 1000000;

    $packages = WC()->shipping()->get_packages()[0]['rates'];

    foreach ( array_keys( $packages ) as $key ) {
        
        if ( ( $packages[$key]->cost > 0 ) && ( $packages[$key]->cost < $the_cheapest_cost ) ) {
            $the_cheapest_cost = $packages[$key]->cost;
            $transport_label   = $packages[$key]->label;    
            $method_id         = $packages[$key]->id;
        }
    }

    if(get_option('atransport')){
        update_option('atransport', $transport_label);
    }else{
        add_option('atransport', $transport_label);
    }

    return $method_id;

}  

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_methods_label_names', 20, 2 ); 
function change_shipping_methods_label_names( $rates, $package ) {

    $transport = get_option('atransport');
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( __( 'Free Shipping', 'woocommerce' ) == $rate->label ){ 
            $rates[$rate_key]->label = __( 'FreeShipping -' . $transport, 'woocommerce' ); // New label name
        }
    }
    delete_option('atransport');
    return $rates;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate a loop of `$rates` and get the cheapest method. then based on the found cheapest method you can change the label. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_other_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100, 1 );
function hide_other_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {

    $cheapest_method = '';

    // Loop through shipping rates
    if ( is_array( $rates ) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
            // Set variables when the rate is cheaper than the one saved
            if ( empty( $cheapest_method ) || $rate->cost < $cheapest_method->cost ) {
                $cheapest_method = $rate;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the cheapest rate when possible
    if ( ! empty( $cheapest_method ) ) {

        $free = array();
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( $rate->id === $cheapest_method->id ) {

                if ( __( 'Free Shipping', 'woocommerce' ) == $rate->label ){

                    $rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                    // Here we append the labbelled saved price formated display
                    $rates[ $rate_id ]->label = 'Free Shipping '.$rates[ $rate_id ]->label;

                    break; // stop the loop
                }
            }
        }
        return  $rates;
    }

    return  $rates;

}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhautik! Thanks for your answer. What if I still want to show the other shipping methods available? I want to show to the user which shipping method will be used if he chooses free shipping, but some customers might want to choose an specific shipping company or a faster service... =)

Comment: Yes as you can see other shipping methods are available as well.